Is it possible to intermingle or overlap braces?
I'm trying to do something like the statement below where I group elements by two with overbrace and by three below with underbrace.
Unfortunately these are intermingled, and the result with the naive approach is broken
$n^4-n^2=\overset{\LARGE{\overbrace{\hphantom{n\cdot(n-1)}}^{\Large{\text{div by 2}}}\overbrace{\hphantom{n\cdot(n+1)}}^{\Large{\text{div by 2}}}}}{n\cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)}_\text{div by 3}}$
I managed to get a somehow presentable rendering by stacking an hphantom and tuning the size of the fonts but the code is super ugly, also the gap between above and below braces is not the same, as well as their boldness.
Is there some nicer way than this ?
n^4-n^2=\overset{\LARGE{\overbrace{\hphantom{n\cdot(n-1)}}^{\Large{\text{div by 2}}}\overbrace{\hphantom{n\cdot(n+1)}}^{\Large{\text{div by 2}}}}}{n\cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)}_\text{div by 3}}

Related on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12963/28519, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297/28519. I haven't checked if any of those solutions works with MathJax.

Also, the example in the question would be a good one to use, but it is unclear where the overbraces are meant to be. There is one over $n\cdot (n-1)$ and another over $n\cdot(n+1)$ or are they meant to be together as one overbrace?

they are separated, I just used a today's question asking to prove divisibility by $12$ as a support for my question, but I faced this issue before and told myself, it would be nice if I could do this.

From TEX Stack Exchange, use \rlap to move formulas back horizontally and \phantom to adjust the width of the braces:
$\rlap{\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }2}}\ \ \cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}$
\rlap{\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }2}}\ \ \cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}
Alternatively, use \kern or \hskip for negative spacing:
$\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }2}\kern-3.75em\cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}$
$\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }\kern-3.75em\cdot\underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}$
and
$\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }2}\hskip{-3.5em}{\cdot\ \underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}}$
\overbrace{n\phantom{\cdot (n-1)\cdot}}^{\text{div by }2}\hskip{-3.5em}{\cdot\ \underbrace{(n-1)\cdot \overbrace{n\cdot(n-1)}^{\text{div by }2}}_{\text{div by }3}}

They all look very nice, and I learnt some new syntax.
